# Automapper Project using

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I am currently using automapper in my backend to map objects to models. 
I recently decided to use the following code to handle all my timezone conversions:

```
  cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>()
  .ProjectUsing(i => DbFunctions.AddHours(i, offset.Hours));

  cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>()
  .ProjectUsing(i => DbFunctions.AddHours(i, offset.Hours).Value);


  Object.ProjectTo<ObjectModel>().SingleOrDefault();
```

then it works fine and the object is mapped and timezone converted

However when i am using the following code in my business layer to do a single object mapping:

```
Mapper.Map<Object, ObjectModel>(singleRecord);
```

It Gives an error : 
This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

stack trace :

```
at System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(Nullable`1 timeValue, Nullable`1 addValue)
   at lambda_method(Closure , DateTime , DateTime , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Inventory , InventoryModel , ResolutionContext )
```

Mapper.Map is important to use in specific scenarios and i also don't want to project single records.

is there a way round this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AutoMapper will build a mapping `Func<TSource, TDestination>>` to be used by `Map` method by compiling the `Expression<TFunc<TSource, TDestionation>>` passed to `ProjectUsing` and used by `ProjectTo`, because usually it's enough and works. But not with EF canonical functions.

You could override that behavior by specifying a different conversion to be used with `Map` method by providing explicitly both `ProjectUsing` and `ConvertUsing`:

```
var map1 = cfg.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>();
map1.ProjectUsing(i => DbFunctions.AddHours(i, offset.Hours));
map1.ConvertUsing(i => i?.AddHours(offset.Hours));

var map2 = cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>();
map2.ProjectUsing(i => DbFunctions.AddHours(i, offset.Hours).Value);
map2.ConvertUsing(i => i.AddHours(offset.Hours));
```

Comment: Hey @ivan , thanks for your answer, i think its working and i am implementing it as we speak.

Comment: Can you explain something to me : 
Is projectusing running on the Database level ? 
Is Convert using running on the Cpu level ? what does EF Canonical functions mean and do ?

Comment: (1) EF Canonical functions are the ones from `DbFunctions`. As you noticed, they are not meant to be executed. Just are like known "placeholders" inside the `IQueryable` expression tree, and EF query translator maps them to the corresponding database function calls inside SQL query. (2) Yes, since `ConvertUsing` receives a `Func<...>` (read - code), it cannot be mapped to SQL, so it's used by `Map` methods which operate on in memory objects.

Comment: You're a legend Ivan ! 
Are you looking for a full time job by any chance ? Location is Dubai

Comment: Hehe, thanks, glad it helped you. And no, appreciate, but I like where I live now :)

Comment: Hi ivan, i have a small issue  and was hoping you can help me with, when i used the Mapper.Map function now , i retrieve the date as follows :

console.log(new Date("2017-06-06T12:09:32.3757652Z"))
Tue Jun 06 2017 16:09:32 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time) 
This date is wrong as its off by 4 hours


However, when i use projectto, i get the following result which is correct

console.log(new Date("2017-06-06T12:09:32.377"))
 Tue Jun 06 2017 12:09:32 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)

Comment: Hi DaGeek, Hope you are not calling `Map` with date retrieved by `ProjectTo`, because the `offset.Hours` will be applied twice? Or if the `Map` is used to convert dates back from view model/dto to entity model, the `ConverTo` should use `-offset.Hours`?

Comment: No iam not , Iam actually  using the following piece of code :

var returnback = Mapper.Map<RequestListModel>(_unitOfWork.RequestsRepository.GetRequestByID(_Request.Request_ID));

there's a field called 'Created_Date' which is being received differently when i run mapper.map vs projectto. However i noticed that the value for the date property "kind" is = utc when using map and = 'undefined' for project to. So the browser is obviously is adding the timezone because it knows its UTC, how can i override the datetime Kind property ? i think that would work

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow the case, but you could try [`SpecifyKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that expose EDM canonical >functions for use in DbContext or ObjectContext LINQ to Entities queries.

So the error is to be expected because the projection is not executed in a LINQ to Entities query.

The `DbFuncions.AddHours()` call is translated to a database function. Since in your business layer you're not passing an entity but an object, the error is thrown.

You have two ways to work around the problem:
1. Use a different mapping logic in your bussiness layer.
2. Use a mapping logic that does not depend on the `DbFunctions` class so that it can be used in your DAL and business layer.