# AutoMapper ConvertUsing is not called

Tags: c#, automapper

I have simple task: just map one class to another. For some fields I have complex logic, depends on 2 or more fields, so, I try to use `ConvertUsing` (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)

I use AutoMapper 10.0.0

My code is:

Source class:

```
public class DeviceStatusHistory
{
    public DeviceStatusHistory()
    {
        DateChange = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    public int? RequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceManagementRequest Request { get; set; }

    public DeviceStatus OldStatus { get; set; }
    public DeviceStatus NewStatus { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChange { get; set; }
}
```

DTO class:

```
public class DeviceChangeStatusDto
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIMEI { get; set; }
    public string OldStatus { get; set; }
    public string NewStatus { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateChange { get; set; }
}
```

and Automapper class:

```
public class AutoMapperEfDeviceManagement : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public AutoMapperEfDeviceManagement()
    {
        CreateMap<DeviceStatusHistory, DeviceChangeStatusDto>().ConvertUsing<DeviceChangeStatusConverter>();
    }
}
```

where `DeviceChangeStatusConverter` is defined as:

```
public class DeviceChangeStatusConverter : ITypeConverter<DeviceStatusHistory, DeviceChangeStatusDto>
{
    public DeviceChangeStatusDto Convert(DeviceStatusHistory source, DeviceChangeStatusDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = new DeviceChangeStatusDto
        {
            CarrierName = source.Device.CarrierId.HasValue ? source.Device.Carrier.Name : null,
            DeviceId = source.DeviceId,
            DateChange = source.DateChange,
            DeviceIMEI = source.Device.IMEI,
            DeviceName = source.Device.GetFriendlyDetailedName(),
            NewStatus = CommonHelper.SplitByWords(source.NewStatus.ToString())
        };

        // some complex logic here

        return destination;
    }
}
```

but when I try to map it:

```
var list = _context.DeviceStatusHistory
.Where(a => ((int)a.NewStatus < 100) && a.DateChange.Date == date.Date)
.ProjectTo<DeviceChangeStatusDto>(_mapperConfig)
.ToList();
```

where `_mapperConfig` is:

```
        _mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperEfDeviceManagement>();
        });
```

It maps looks like it was declared simple as :

```
CreateMap<DeviceStatusHistory, DeviceChangeStatusDto>();
```

so, only the same properties are mapped, converter is not called (debugger says the same).
What is wrong?

ADDED:

approach like:

```
        CreateMap<DeviceStatusHistory, DeviceChangeStatusDto>()
            .ConvertUsing((source, destination) =>
            {
                destination.CarrierName = source.Device.CarrierId.HasValue ? source.Device.Carrier.Name : null;
```

does not work too

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman what is wrong and why my post not acceptable for minimal reproducible example? Seems, it's real bug of Automapper

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#createprojection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It is not a bug, it's a known limitation. Basically AutoMapper can't convert some custom method into SQL (or translate it into the form which will allow your ORM to translate that into SQL) so it can't use your type converter in `ProjectTo`.

A little bit more details:

From the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html):

> The `.ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>()` will tell `AutoMapper`’s mapping engine to emit a `select` clause to the `IQueryable` that will inform entity framework that it only needs to query the `Name` column of the `Item` table, same as if you manually projected your `IQueryable` to an `OrderLineDTO` with a `Select` clause.

And from [Custom Type Conversion](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#custom-type-conversion) section:

> Occasionally, you need to completely replace a type conversion from a source to a destination type. In normal runtime mapping, this is accomplished via the `ConvertUsing` method. To perform the analog in LINQ projection, use the `ConvertUsing` method: `cfg.CreateProjection<Source, Dest>().ConvertUsing(src => new Dest { Value = 10 });`
> The expression-based `ConvertUsing` is slightly more limited than `Func`-based `ConvertUsing` overloads as only what is allowed in an `Expression` and the underlying LINQ provider will work.

And [Supported mapping options](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options):

> Not all mapping options can be supported, as the expression generated must be interpreted by a LINQ provider. Only what is supported by LINQ providers is supported by AutoMapper:

> - MapFrom (Expression-based)
> - ConvertUsing (Expression-based)
> - Ignore
> - NullSubstitute
> - Value transformers
> - IncludeMembers

> Not supported:

> - Condition
> - SetMappingOrder
> - UseDestinationValue
> - MapFrom (Func-based)
> - Before/AfterMap
> - Custom resolvers
> - **Custom type converters**
> - ForPath
> - Value converters
> - Any calculated property on your domain object

Comment: but it does not work even for simple things, like: `                .ConvertUsing((source, destination) =>
                    {
                        destination.CarrierName = source.Device.CarrierId.HasValue ? source.Device.Carrier.Name : null;`

Comment: @OlegSh it does not matter if it is "simple thing" or not. What matters if it is `Func`-based or [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)-based. The overload you are using accepts `Func<...>` (check the signature), therefore it can't be translated into SQL.

Comment: This expression can be translated into SQL, it works in many other similar cases LinqToEntities

Comment: @OlegSh the one in the question is not rewritable as is due to the `// some complex logic here` and `GetFriendlyDetailedName()`, `CommonHelper.SplitByWords(...)` calls cause your ORM will not know how to translate that into SQL. As for the "simple one" - without full setup it's hard to say if it can be  rewritten.

Comment: @OlegSh yes such expression can be translated, but the overload used here - `.ConvertUsing((source, destination) => { destination.CarrierName = source.Device.CarrierId.HasValue ? source.Device.Carrier.Name : null;` is not an expression, it is a `Func` (check the signature). And `Func` are not translatable (at least without some dirty magic).

Comment: Thank you. But why Automapper works so rough? Without throwing exception, just ignore part of code?

Comment: @OlegSh my pleasure! TBH - no idea. I would say that this is a question better addressed at their github.