# Static function not getting the data without .Include (C#, EFC)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

### SETUP

I'm creating an API with C# + Entity Framework Core.

This is how tables are setup

[image]

and I'm creating an API call for `Drawdown` `GetById`

With `GetById` I want to

- get the all fields of `Drawdown`,
- add array of all `Funding`s and their fields in the `Service`,
- populate field `Cost` for each `DrawdowFundingCost` that exists,
- **and one more field that's calculated on server side called `ExpenditureToDate` that's a sum of all `DrawdownFundingCost`s for each `Funding`.**

In the end, JSON should look like this:

```json
{
    "Id": 4,
    "ServiceId": 2831,
    // ... other Drawdown fields
    "FundingCosts": [
        {
            "FundingId": 8,
            "ServiceId": 2831,
            // ... other Funding fields
            "ExpenditureToDate": 246, // calculated in API
            "Cost": 123 // got from FundingCost
        },
        {
            "FundingId": 9,
            "ServiceId": 2831,
            // ... other Funding fields
            "ExpenditureToDate": 246, // calculated in API
            "Cost": 123 // got from FundingCost
        },
    ]
}
```

I've got my `DrawdownController`, `DrawdownService` and `DrawdownMapper` files.
Controller receives the HTTP GET request, calls service, service creates a query and calls the mapper to convert the EF Entity to DTO, then service sends the DTO back to controller and it sends the response.

Skipping the Controller, as it's called successfully and the problem's not there.

Service function:

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResult<DrawdownDto>> GetById(GetDrawdownByIdQuery query, CancellationToken token)
{
    var getByIdQuery = _db.Drawdown
        .Where(x => x.Id == query.Id && x.DeletedDate == null)
        .AsNoTracking();

    var getByIdMapper = getByIdQuery.Select(_mapper.ConvertToEditDto(query.Lcid));

    var getByIdData = await getByIdMapper.SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);

    if (getByIdData == null)
        return ServiceResult<DrawdownEditDto>.NotFound($"Drawdown with Id {query.Id} not found.");

    return ServiceResult<DrawdownEditDto>.Success(getByIdData);
}
```

Mapper function:

```cs
public Expression<Func<DrawdownEntity, DrawdownDto>> ConvertToEditDto(int lcid)
{
    return source => new DrawdownEditDto
    {
        Id = source.Id,
        ServiceId = source.ServiceId,
        // ... other Drawdown fields
        FundingCosts = source.Service.Funding
            .Where(x => x.DeletedDate == null)
            .Select(x => new DrawdownFundingCostEditDto
            {
                FundingId = x.Id,
                ServiceId = x.ServiceId,
                // ... other Drawdown fields
                ExpenditureToDate = ExpenditureToDate(x),
                Cost = source.DrawdownFundingCost.Where(q => q.DeletedDate == null).FirstOrDefault(q => q.FundingId == x.Id) != null 
                ? source.DrawdownFundingCost.Where(q => q.DeletedDate == null).FirstOrDefault(q => q.FundingId == x.Id).Cost
                : 0,
            }).ToList()
    };
}

private static decimal ExpenditureToDate(FundingEntity f)
    => f.DrawdownFundingCost.Where(x => x.DeletedDate == null).Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

---

### PROBLEM

Using this static function `ExpenditureToDate(FundingEntity f)` always returns 0.

**Solution 1:**

I add some `Include`s in the service function like this:

```cs
var getByIdQuery = _db.Drawdown
    .Include(x => x.Service)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Funding)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.DrawdownFundingCost)
    .Where(x => x.Id == query.Id && x.DeletedDate == null)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

**Solution 2:**

I just use the query instead of the static function in mapper like this:

```
ExpenditureToDate = x.DrawdownFundingCost.Where(x => x.DeletedDate == null).Sum(x => x.Cost),
```

---

### QUESTIONS

How do I achieve the code cleanliness by using my static function in mapper without using all the `Include`s in my service?

Why isn't the static function catching the data without the `Include`s in service function?

Is there something that I'm missing?

---

### BOTTOM LINE

I get that `Include`s are eager loading the data, so that's a loss for performance, but as the code is used in multiple places (in Mapper) it should be put into function, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Of course, bottom line is that I don't make it slow, so solution 2 is what I'd choose if I had to pick one.

Comment: I see all of your problems. Solution is to use LINQKit. Do you agree to use third party libraries? If not it can be emulated.

Comment: It seems that you need to consider using library like AutoMapper (Or LINQKit's `AsExpandable` with expression combination if you want to avoid mapping libraries). Basically this is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803061/2501279

Comment: You can probably avoid LINQKit *and* simplify your code a lot if you do what LINQ itself does. Instead of generating an Expression, pass `IQueryable<DrawdownEntity>` to `ConvertToEditDto`, apply the `Select` you want and return an `IQueryable<DrawdownEntityDto>`. That's the same as using `var query2=query1.Select(........);` in your code and extracting the entire clause into a method